# Export inherited Interface Docs in C# ASP.Net to Swagger OAS3

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, swagger, openapi

How can can I export the documentation of inherited interfaces?

Lets assume two interfaces with comments:

```cs
/// <summary>Interface A</summary>
public interface A {
    /// <summary>Attribute A</summary>
    string AttributeA;
}
/// <summary>Interface B</summary>
public interface B : A {
    /// <summary>Attribute B</summary>
    string AttributeB;
}
```

I configured swagger within the `Startup` class as follows:

```cs
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
    var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
    c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
});
```

My REST web methods always return objects of type `B`. The problem is that created docs only contain
the schema description of `B`. The information *Interface A* with *Attribute A* are missing in the schema overview as well as in the example value section.

Comment: I've created a PullRequest that solves this issue: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/pull/2182 Hope it gets merged soon.

Answer (score 2):

Not quite what I need but close. I've updated *Swashbucke.AspNetCore* from v5.0.0 to v5.6.3 and used the `UseAllOfForInheritance()` method to [enable inheritance](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/README.md#enabling-inheritance).

```
c.UseAllOfForInheritance();
c.SelectSubTypesUsing(t =>
{
    if (t.IsInterface)
    {
        return t.GetInterfaces();
    }
    return Enumerable.Empty<Type>();
});
```

`SelectSubTypeUsing` will resolve all interfaces for any type which is an interface. For type `B` the array `[typeof(A), typeof(B)]` is returned. Finally the schema of `A` will be part of the documention.

**But the "example values" still mentions only *Attribute B*. I'm still wondering how to solve this issue.**